# Must be string or read-only character buffer, not Path

Tags: python, image-processing, svg

I'm working with an SVG file and I'm extracting the paths as demonstrated below:

```
 from svg.path import parse_path
 import svgwrite
 from svgpathtools import svg2paths

 f=open("a.txt",'w')
 paths, attributes = svg2paths('cou.svg')
 for k, v in enumerate(attributes):
     path_alt = parse_path(v['d'])
     f.write(path_alt)
```

Doing

```
> print(path_alt[0])
```

gives me the following:

```
Path(Line(start=(410+224j), end=(411+227j)), Line(start=(411+227j), end=(410+227j)), Line(start=(410+227j), end=(410+224j)), closed=False)
```

Whereas

```
> f.write(path_alt)
```

gives me the error

```
must be string or read-only character buffer, not Path
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: `f.write(s)` writes `s` into your file `f`, so you should be passing in the content of what you want to write into, rather than the file path.

Comment: I know , i want  to write this :Line(start=(410+224j), end=(411+227j)), Line(start=(411+227j), end=(410+227j))

Comment: You will have to convert that to string. Try `str(path_alt)`.